# Width of string in Pixels

Tags: c, linux, string, fonts, pixel

Can anyone tell how can I calculate width of a string in pixels,provided font size in pixels?
I have to do it in C under linux?

Comment: Very much depends on what engine you use to render your text, as different engines might deal differently with hinting, kerning information, and so on. You'll definitely have to not only provide the font size, but the font itself as well.

Comment: well,If I provide font also,but what is the way to proceed?I am stucked at the start itself because I don't know how to get height to width ratio of English alphabets.Where can I get this?

Comment: Will you be printing the text as well, or just measuring it? If you print it, tell us how you want to print it. If you only want to measure, imagine you would want to print it, probably using libraries from the provided answers, and see what measurement information those provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like the [FreeType library](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-toc.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that by yourself, unless you have a fixed point font (where every character is always X pixels wide). In that case, of course total width = PixelPerChar * strlen(String).

In the general case of proportional fonts, and if characters may be "pushed close" to one another, for example A and V (an operation called "kerning"), you need to ask to the font rendering library, e.g. libGD2. Such libraries usually supply the bounding box of a string, given the font file, size, orientation and other parameters.

Example for GD2 using [gdImageStringFT](https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.3.0/files/gdft-c.html#gdImageStringFT):

```
int bbox[8]; // x,y of the rectangle bounding the text:
// see manual

gdImageStringFT(NULL,  // "Tell me only"
      bbox,0,
      "/home/lserni/fonts/Verdana.ttf",18,
      0.0,0,0,"Hello world"); 

if (checks on bbox OK)
{
   gdImageStringFT(gdHandle, bbox, 0, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most basic scenario, assuming it is a fixed length font:

```
int string_width = strlen(str) * CHAR_WIDTH_PX;
```

Where str is the C string and CHAR_WIDTH_PX is the character width of the font.

But of course in different frameworks and systems things are done in different ways. To help you with that, we need more information about your environment.

Comment: I can know CHAR_WIDTH_PX for fixed width font,but I have to do it for proportional fonts.

Comment: @ShraddhaK You should probably specify that in your question.