# Howto determine the size of a text in the current font in wxTextCtrl

Tags: c, wxwidgets, sizer

Is there a way to determine the x,y dimensions of the text display (in pixels) based on the currently selected font? In current wxWindow and setup sizers.

It depends on the size of the widget. But this one is determined by the objects above. How to find out how much the text would take if it were to be printed in full.

I need the wxSize in pixels of the text from wxTextCtrl current sizers.
For initialize:

```
SetInitialSize( size of text );
SetMinSize( size of text );
```

Comment: ,what problem you are trying to solve? I.e., why do you need to know the size of the text in pixels?

Comment: Probably a duplicate with: [Width of string in Pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410375/width-of-string-in-pixels) ?

Comment: @Luuk this link is not in wxwidgets and is about other situation

Comment: You need to do some research, when you had done that you should have found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529463/724039

Comment: This function get unwraped text. I need real wraped text. and C not python

Comment: @Rumburak, why do you need that? What you are trying to do? How do you create the control? How do you add it to sizer (if you use them)? Maybe there is an alternative way of doing what you want...

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710869/wxwidgets-c-dynamically-wrapping-wxstatictext-in-dialog
 I need setup minimal size this statictext in vertical. It is bigger than main window but I have virtual canvas and scroller. I need widget with max size in vertical. Setup SetMinSize() bigger than real window but smaller than virtual window.